# DynamoDB PutItem creating multiple items with same partition key when it should be replacing the item

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local

I am using DynamoDB locally with NoSQL Workbench and an Express API.

I have a table generated as such:

```
const params = {
  AttributeDefinitions: [
    {
      AttributeName: 'id',
      AttributeType: 'S',
    },
  ],
  KeySchema: [
    {
      AttributeName: 'id',
      KeyType: 'HASH',
    }
  ]
  TableName: table.name,
  ProvisionedThroughput: {
    ReadCapacityUnits: 1,
    WriteCapacityUnits: 1
  },
}

dynamo.createTable(params).promise() // ... simplified version
```

I update an item using the DocumentClient as such:

```
const db = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient(configOptions);
const data = await db.put({
  TableName,
  Item,
}) // ... interact with result
```

Occasionally, it creates a new item in DynamoDB with the exact same `id` value even though I created it as a HASH and made it the partition key.

However, it doesn't happen *every* time. I can't seem to recreate it consistently.

Is there something I'm doing wrong with how I'm creating this table or updating this item that is leading to this?

See items 97/98 here, this image is of my NoSQL Workbench and you can see there are two items with the same `id`

[image: See items 97/98 here, this image is of my NoSQL Workbench and you can see there are two items with the same id]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the issue. What is the behavior you are expecting and what is happening? I think you are misunderstanding the hash key, but I need to be sure I understand the problem before offering an explaination.

Comment: By definition, that is not possible.  Did you define a sort key on your actual table?  That would mean the Primary Key is HASH+SORT and would allow for duplicate HASH key values..

Comment: Note that [PutItem](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_PutItem.html) will replace an old item that has the same primary key. It doesn't yield a primary/unique key violation by default (though you can achieve this with a conditional PutItem).

Comment: @JasonWadsworth The expected behavior is that the PutItem replaces the existing item and uses the `id` attribute to know which item to replace. 

The resulting behavior is that randomly there seems to be an additional item created with the same ID instead of replacing it. This then leads to bugs in subsequent actions taken on the DB that interact with these items because they aren't unique. I'll add a screenshot to the OP.

Comment: @Charles That is my thought as well, yet it's happening. Which made me wonder if I didn't create the table correctly to make these items unique. Or if I'm using PutItem incorrectly?

Comment: @Charles to clarify, I created the Table using the code above. I don't think I defined a sort key unless there is some default that I need to unset.

Comment: How are you running docker locally?  Do you have the latest version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting in touch with AWS Support, it turns out this is a known issue with using DynamoDB locally. They provided the following guidance for fixing it:

> As you mentioned that you are using the docker image for deploying
> DynamoDB local [1], please go ahead and remove the
> '-optimizeDbBeforeStartup' flag given in step 2 ('Docker tab') (and
> then save it as docker-compose.yml):
>
> 1. Removing '-optimizeDbBeforeStartup' from the argument list:
>    ========== .. .. command: "-jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb -dbPath ./data" .. ..
>    ==========
> 2. Create tables and insert item
> 3. docker-compose down
> 4. docker-compose up